# Remove dots from column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace

I would like to remove a series of dots from the values in a table using SQL

Example:

```
ID        Values
1         Automobiles……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….
2         Furniture……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………
3         Leasehold Improvements…………………………………………….
4         Land………………………………………………………..……………………………………………………………………………………..
5         Equipment………………………………………….………………………………………….
```

Required output:

```
ID        Values
1         Automobiles
2         Furniture
3         Leasehold Improvements
4         Land
5         Equipment
```

Comment: Have you a question? Have you tried anything? Did you use the [`regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) tag because SQL Server does not have support for regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming no leading or embedded ellipses.  Note the "Fail-Safe"  `[Values]+'…'`

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Values] varchar(500))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Automobiles……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….')
,(2,'Furniture……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………')
,(3,'Leasehold Improvements…………………………………………….')
,(4,'Land………………………………………………………..……………………………………………………………………………………..')
,(5,'Equipment………………………………………….………………………………………….')
 
Select *
      ,NewValue = substring([Values],1,charindex('…',[Values]+'…')-1)
 from @YourTable
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
 Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[Values] varchar(500))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'Automobiles……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………….')
,(2,'Furniture……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………')
,(3,'Leasehold Improvements…………………………………………….')
,(4,'Land………………………………………………………..……………………………………………………………………………………..')
,(5,'Equipment………………………………………….………………………………………….')
 
Select *
     ,replace(replace([values],'…',''),'.','')
 from @YourTable
```